# Using child_process.fork changed __filename and __dirname?

Tags: node.js

Hi I used the following code to create a server process.

```
child_process.fork('./src/server.js');
```

But in the server process, the __filename and __dirname changed to '/' and '/index.js' respectively.

```
// in server.js
console.log(__dirname);  // output as /
console.log(__filename); // output as /index.js
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I realised made a mistake when using webpack. I should set the the following in config.

```
{
  node: {
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
}
```